# Stream/read line delimited huge log file and store it to a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, stream, readline

I am having a huge line delimited JSON file (around 10 million lines and more). How do I stream it and store selected attributes to another variable for further processing/filtering?

I tried below code

```
var readline = require('readline');
var x = []
var x = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/huge_log_file'),
    terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
    x.push(line['id'])
});
```

Here I am trying to extract the attribute `id` from the log file and store it in variable `x` which I need for later filtering. Here the variable `x` is coming empty. I am not sure what is the reason. Is there any other way to do it?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to parse the json.

Comment: @tkausl - I did add `var x = JSON.parse(line)` line before the push line. But with that I was able to parse the line but was not able to push to variable `x`
```
var temp = JSON.parse(line)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things which are wrong in this code.

1. You are re-defining `x` which you should remove.
2. The `line` variable is a string which contains the `id` maybe but it's not a property that you can extract by doing `line['id']` without first parsing the string.

Assuming the log is in `json`, the code will look like:

```js
var readline = require('readline');
var x = []
readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('/huge_log_file'),
    terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
    var log = JSON.parse(line);
    x.push(log['id']);
});
```

If the log is not json, you need to parse it in another form, but that's the gist.

Comment: i tried this way. I can print `log['id']` inside the on(line) code but I am not able to push the data to the array `x`. Nothing is getting pushed and empty array is getting printed.

Comment: This is how the sample log file looks like 
```
{"id":628, "code":"US", "class":"3543"}
{"id":23543, "code":"US", "class":"56878"}
{"id":3465345, "code":"US", "class":"2342"}
........
{"id":1432, "code":"US", "class":"235"}
```

Comment: THis looks like Json, so the code in the answer should work.

Comment: It is not working. I have exactly used the code shared here. I am using node version 10. I dont know what is the issue too.

Comment: You would need to share any error or log output to get more help. "not working" is not very helpful.

Comment: Can you point me towards how to share the error log ? I am a newbie here.